# How to select div in javascript?

Tags: javascript, select

In a javascript form, I want to select a div (just one div) to apply a function for everything inside, for example, I want to select the first div and apply a function for the other div inside

```html
<p>Select a maintenance drone:</p>

<div>
  <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
    <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
  </div>
  <label for="huey">Huey</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
  <label for="louie">Louie</label>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "apply a function"? In general, the easiest way of selecting a div is to provide it with a unique(!) `id` attribute and use `document.getElemenById('the_id')` or `document.querySelector('#the_id')`

Comment: i mean, if i chose the main div, and i call a function , this function will be applied to the other div inside

Comment: If you have the outer div in a JS variable, you can call `.querySelector(...)` on it to get to a child element.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways, by id, by class name or by query selector

```js
var myBox = document.getElementById("myBox");                 //By id
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("paper");           //By class
var theBox = document.getElementsByTagName("div");            //By tag name

var seleccionarId = document.querySelector("#myBox");         //By id
var seleccionarClase = document.querySelector(".paper");      //By class
var seleccionarElemento = document.querySelector("div");      //By tag name
```

```html
<div id="myBox" class="paper"> Im a box </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to select an element using HTML. One of the best ways is to target an element by its id. For your code, this would require adding an id to the parent div. To select an element by its **id** write:

```
let element = document.getElementById('elementID');
```

You can select the elements children of the element with:

```
element.children; //This returns an array of the children
```

For your specific problem, I would write:

```
let parentDiv = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
let children = parentDiv.children;
let childDiv = children.find(isDiv => isDiv.tagName === 'DIV'); //returns the first element that is a div
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply a function to each element within the DIV or any other element

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');

function handler(target, callback) {
    for (let i = 0; i < target.childNodes.length; i++) {
        const child = target.childNodes[i];
        callback.call(child);
        if (child.childNodes.length) {
            handler(child, callback);
        }
    }
}

function action() {
    console.log('node: ', this.nodeName);
}

handler(target, action);
```

```html
<p>Select a maintenance drone:</p>

    <div id="target">
        <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" checked>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey">
            <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
        </div>
        <label for="huey">Huey</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie">
        <label for="louie">Louie</label>
    </div>
```